# Bad request API google Python

Tags: python, request

I was getting usually send the request by the code below, but out of nowhere he started the mistake and do not want to send. Could anyone help me?

The code:

```
import urllib2
import json


url = "https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=AIzaSyBtRCSB8tZ7u0F9U6txJeMwMcYRdJ9b4B8"
code = {
 "request": {
  "passengers": {
   "adultCount": 1,
   "childCount": 1,
   "infantInSeatCount": 1
  },
  "slice": [
   {
    "origin": "SSA",
    "destination": "REC",
    "date": "2015-05-01",
    "maxStops": 1,
    "permittedDepartureTime": {
     "earliestTime": "09:00",
     "latestTime": "16:00"
    }
   },
   {
    "origin": "REC",
    "destination": "SSA",
    "date": "2015-05-20",
    "maxStops": 1
   }
  ],
  "maxPrice": "BRL 200.00",
  "refundable": "false",
  "solutions": 20
 }
}



jsonreq = json.dumps(code, encoding = 'utf-8')
req = urllib2.Request(url, jsonreq, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
flight = urllib2.urlopen(req)
response = flight.read()
flight.close()
print(response)
```

The Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Francisco\Desktop\Projeto\test1.py", line 41, in <module>
    flight = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 475, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Comment: Please avoid usage of off-site resources like pastebin - they can go down leading to link rot.

Answer (score 0):

The 400 error will return information what is incorrect:

> Invalid inputs for request id \"nL8TcZS7RG7DPB70m0MNw9\": Brl 200.00
>   is not a valid value for x.maxPrice."

In this case the space is causing the trouble. Replace

```
BRL 200.00
```

with

```
BRL200.00
```

Link to documentation for [maxPrice](https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/v1/trips/search)